# Can I get a Messaging app working together with an iPhone (5s)

Tags: software-recommendation, iphone

I know there are ways to message on Ubuntu if you have an Android, I am wondering if it is possible to message when you have an iPhone.

The best would be an iMessage Client for Ubuntu, but I don't think those exist, so I am fine using another program (it could use my email, but preferably my phone number).

Comment: There are no completed projects about associating Apple devices to a Linux machine. You'll need complete server solutions, or experimental utilities.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such way to use "iMessage" On Ubuntu.

If you want a simple IM Service, I Think this is what you are looking for: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pidgin/

I dont think there is such way to Use SMS as a native client on ubuntu.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

### Signal

**Signal** provides an excellent Client running on all platforms using the same account as your Phone. The Signal mobile app runs on iOS and Android.

Comment: Plus, Signal is open source!

Answer (score 0):

You can send and receive text messages using [Pinger](http://www.pinger.com/content/pinger.html), either through your phone number or the Pinger service, to and from your own account on the [Textfree Web app](http://www.pinger.com/tfw/) or to any other online service that sends and receives online texts, of which there are many to be found [on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=text%20free%20online&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).